# welcome screen glimpse while data is loading from database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-livedata

My app loads a list of training entities from the database into a `RecyclerView`. There's a `welcomeTextView` with `visibility="@{viewModel.listHasNoData}"`. It replaces the `RecyclerView` if the database is empty yet or if the user has deleted all data. The problem is that I have a split-second glimpse of this `welcomeTextView` every time I open the app while the data is being loaded. 
I've found a walkaround by saving a `boolean` `isDatabaseEmpty` to `SharedPreference`s when closing the app. But I believe there should be a more graceful solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set visibility of `welcomeTextView` to gone by default. After the query into database , if there is no data then continue with the same logic . `visibility="@{viewModel.listHasNoData}"`

Comment: Thank you, it works and it's only 1 line of code to get the job done.

Comment: Ευχαριστώ, Βασίλη, και Καλά Χριστούγεννα

Comment: @Anastasiya If you found my answer correct plz check it as correct and / or upvote. Καλά Χριστούγεννα!!

Comment: I did, but I'm a new user and my reputation is less than 15 so far, so the publicly displayed score didn't change